# c# Get all elements of a struct list based on one Filed only

Tags: c#

I have a list which is defined on a struct type of 3 elements:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
    public string Field2;
}
```

My list is defined by

```
List<MyStruct> MyList
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a new list of type string which filters my struct list by looking for one Field only.
Example: Get all Field1 elements in the new list (just strings).
Is this possible?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: How about `MyList.Select(ms => ms.Field1).ToList()`?

Comment: Works ok. Thanks

Comment: My idea is to use this new list (List1) and compare it with another list (List2) and create a new list that exclude all common elements in both lists and results on the non common elements. The difficult thing (to me) is that List1 and List2 elements are not a match. List1 elements might be part of List2 elements. Using exclude does not seem to allow IndexOf to compare the two list elements. Do you have an idea?